# Google Oauth consent screen pending validation 3 month no response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console

I have my app consent screen pending for 3 months (not weeks) without ANY Google response. And they don't have any feedback links.

Comment: StackOverflow cannot help you with Google Customer Support problems. You have posted at the wrong place. In my experience, Google replied to you and you either missed the email or it went to SPAM. Delete the client and try again.

Comment: I have already using this client and I have added new permissions to it. There is no google customer support email or anything regarding oauth screens.

Comment: That does not matter, you posted at the wrong place. Google provides support. Sign up for one of their support plans if you still need help.